# Multiple Relay Endpoints in a namespace for exposing a service through Service Bus?

Tags: azure, servicebus, azureservicebus

I cant activate a service that is exposed by two different relay endpoints in the same NAMESPACE but with different addresses. If i delete one of them the service activates fine, so the configuration is fine. I tried changing the type of the binding, changing the namespace, adding two behavior configuration instead of only one but i get always the same error (at the bottom).

Anybody knows if i am missing something? Can i have two relay endpoints in the same namespace?

```xml
<service name="Service">    
        <endpoint contract="IService"  binding="basicHttpRelayBinding" name="b1 "
                  address="http://**NAMESPACE**.servicebus.windows.net/s1"  behaviorConfiguration="credentials"/>    
        <endpoint contract="IService" binding="webHttpRelayBinding" name="wh1"
                  address="https://**NAMESPACE**.servicebus.windows.net/s2"  behaviorConfiguration="credentials"/>                                       
</service>    
<behavior name="credentials">
            <serviceRegistrySettings discoveryMode="Public" displayName="Auxiliar" />
            <transportClientEndpointBehavior>
                <tokenProvider>
                    <sharedSecret issuerName="owner" issuerSecret="**KEY**" />
                </tokenProvider>
            </transportClientEndpointBehavior>
   </behavior>
```

The error is:

> An ExceptionDetail, likely created by IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults=true, whose value is:
>   System.ArgumentException: The value could not be added to the collection, as the collection already contains an item of the same type: 'Microsoft.ServiceBus.NameSettings'. This collection only supports one instance of each type.
>   Parameter name: item
>      at System.Collections.Generic.KeyedByTypeCollection`1.InsertItem(Int32 index, TItem item)
>      at Microsoft.ServiceBus.ServiceRegistrySettings.System.ServiceModel.Description.IEndpointBehavior.AddBindingParameters(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
>      at System.ServiceModel.Description.DispatcherBuilder.AddBindingParameters(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, BindingParameterCollection parameters)
>      at System.ServiceModel.Description.DispatcherBuilder.GetBindingParameters(ServiceHostBase serviceHost, Collection`1 endpoints)
>      at System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceMetadataBehavior.MetadataExtensionInitializer.GenerateMetadata()
>      at System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceMetadataExtension.EnsureInitialized()
>      at System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceMetadataExtension.HttpGetImpl.InitializationData.InitializeFrom(ServiceMetadataExtension extension)
>      at System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceMetadataExtension.HttpGetImpl.GetInitData()
>      at System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceMetadataExtension.HttpGetImpl.TryHandleDocumentationRequest(Message httpGetRequest, String[] queries, Message& replyMessage)
>      at System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceMetadataExtension.HttpGetImpl.ProcessHttpRequest(Message httpGetRequest)
>      at SyncInvokeGet(Object , Object[] , Object[] )
>      at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs)
>      at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc& rpc)
>      at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc& rpc)
>      at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage31(MessageRpc& rpc)
>      at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)

Comment: Are you using `WebServiceHost`? You need to use that for `WebHttpRelayBinding`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you discovered is that [`/behavior/serviceRegistrySettings/@displayName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.servicebus.serviceregistrysettings.displayname.aspx) is colliding for both service definitions. If you want control over the `displayName` for each endpoint, then you need to create separate named behaviors. You need to be ensure **display name** is unique when duplicating endpoint contracts.

#### Option #1 - Remove `displayName`

```xml
   <behavior name="credentials">
     <serviceRegistrySettings discoveryMode="Public" />
       <transportClientEndpointBehavior>
         <tokenProvider>
           <sharedSecret issuerName="owner" issuerSecret="**KEY**" />
         </tokenProvider>
       </transportClientEndpointBehavior>
   </behavior>
```

#### Option #2 - Create duplicate Behavior config

```xml
   <service name="Service">    
        <endpoint contract="IService"  binding="basicHttpRelayBinding" name="b1 "
                  address="http://**NAMESPACE**.servicebus.windows.net/s1"  behaviorConfiguration="basicCredentials"/>    
        <endpoint contract="IService" binding="webHttpRelayBinding" name="wh1"
                  address="https://**NAMESPACE**.servicebus.windows.net/s2"  behaviorConfiguration="webHttpCredentials"/>                                       
   </service>   
   <behavior name="basicCredentials">
     <serviceRegistrySettings discoveryMode="Public" displayName="AuxiliarBasic"/>
       <transportClientEndpointBehavior>
         <tokenProvider>
           <sharedSecret issuerName="owner" issuerSecret="**KEY**" />
         </tokenProvider>
       </transportClientEndpointBehavior>
   </behavior>
   <behavior name="webHttpCredentials">
     <serviceRegistrySettings discoveryMode="Public" displayName="AuxiliarWebHttp"/>
       <transportClientEndpointBehavior>
         <tokenProvider>
           <sharedSecret issuerName="owner" issuerSecret="**KEY**" />
         </tokenProvider>
       </transportClientEndpointBehavior>
   </behavior>
```

Comment: Neither of the alternatives worked for me, did you configure it that way and tried to browse the service?